# Catch all KeyEvent of the application

Tags: java, user-interface, keylistener

I have an application with a main JFrame, and other JDialog and JFrame.

I want the user to be able to take a screenshot whenever he presses F7.

I have a KeyListener on the main frame, but it will not work when the frame lost its focus.

Is there a better to achieve what I want than adding KeyListener to all windows?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found what I was looking for, the [KeyboardFocusManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html), responsible for dispatching all KeyEvent to the focus elements.
Here is how it works:

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
                .addKeyEventDispatcher(e -> {
                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F7 &&
                        e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
                        //do something
                    }
                    return true; //dispatch the event
                });
```